# How can I import css from a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using ZURB Foundation CLI and I can't figured out on how to import css/scss files from node-modules folders.

Comment: Import to where ? Please be more clear on your question

Comment: Example: I want to use Swiper (https://idangero.us/swiper/), it needs both js and css to work. I installed the package via npm, I imported the js file to my app.js using "import Swiper from 'swiper';", but I don't know how to access the css files in the node_modules/swiper folder

Comment: so you mean you want to import some css into your application using webpack ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like `import 'swiper/css/swiper.css'` inside your main.js file.